# How do I install TypeScript 1.1 CTP from source?

Tags: typescript

[TypeScript 1.1 CTP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2014/10/06/announcing-typescript-1-1-ctp.aspx?PageIndex=3#comments) was announced on Oct 6th. I wanted to try it out by revisiting my [TypeScript AST from Node.js](http://blog.ctaggart.com/2014/06/typescript-ast-from-nodejs.html) blog post. With `<TypeScriptToolsVersion>1.1</TypeScriptToolsVersion>` set, Visual Studio 2013 tries to compile using `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.1\tsc.exe`. Running `jake` to build everything from source, it doesn't create a `tsc.exe`. I think it may just be a simple wrapper, so I created the `1.1` folder doing this:

```
copy C:\Projects\TypeScript\built\local "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.1" -r
copy "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\tsc.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.1"
copy "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\tschost.dll" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.1"
copy "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\en" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.1" -r
```

However, when I try compiling my project, I get this error:

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.1\tsc.exe  --module CommonJS --sourcemap --target ES5 --locale en-US "C:\Projects\TsAst\typescriptServices.d.ts" "C:\Projects\TsAst\app.ts" "C:\Projects\TsAst\node.d.ts"
VSTSC(0,0): error : Unable to get property 'replace' of undefined or null reference
Done building project "TsAst.njsproj" -- FAILED.
```

Any ideas? Did I set up the `1.1` folder correctly? If not, how do I install TypeScript 1.1 CTP from source?

Answer (score 1):

The source on github doesn't contain the code for tsc.exe or the Visual Studio plugin.

When you run `jake local` It does generate a tsc.js (among other files) in the built/local folder which is actually kind of the same. you can run it with `node tsc.js` and you will see the same help output you would get when calling tsc.exe.

Comment: That is correct, but I already understand that. That is why I copied the `tsc.exe` and `tschost.dll` to the `1.1` folder I created. The `1.1` folder is a copy of what is built from `jake local`. I'll go ahead and take `tsc.exe` out of the picture and try with just `node tsc.js` to see if I get the same error.